# psql: FATAL: password authentication failed for user error while trying to access psql

Tags: database, postgresql

I am using Windows 10 and just installed Psql (9.6.4) for it. While installing, it asked me to enter password for the superuser 'postgres' which i entered lets say, 'asdfasdf'. 
So after installing, I check the version with `psql --version` and it shows the current version so I guess it installed correctly. 
But when i go to my git bash and enter `psql`, it asks for password, so I enter the password I entered 'asdfasdf' but it says `psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "Bobby"`
I made sure the password was correct and entered it several times, and I am also not sure why it would say authentication failed for user "Bobby". Bobby is just the username for the computer. Am I entering the wrong password when prompted after typing `psql`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

psql by default will use the same username as your OS session is using. You need to first login as postgres or switch to its user (assuming it exists): `su - postgres` or explicitly type username for psql `psql -U postgres`.

Comment: Thanks I just have to do psql -U postgres infront of every postgres command which is a bit annoying.

Comment: You can also create/edit file `.bash_profile` in your home dir and add this line: `export PGUSER=postgres`
This way you can use psql without -U option and it will by default connect as `postgres`. You can read about other environment variables [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html)

Answer (score 1):

In psql tool if you did not specify the user with -U it will use session user which in this case is Booby.

To reset a password under windows have look on this. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44586/forgotten-postgresql-windows-password

Regards